# Emails notifications are not sent from the God gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, delayed-job, god

I use the God gem to monitor my delayed_job processes, so far the gem is doing its job as it should but from some reason I can't get him to send email notifications (i use google apps).
Here are my god file configuration:

```
God::Contacts::Email.defaults do |d|
  d.from_email = 'system@example.com'
  d.from_name = 'Process monitoring'
  d.delivery_method = :smtp
  d.server_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
  d.server_port = 587
  d.server_auth = true
  d.server_domain = 'example.com'
  d.server_user = 'system@example.com'
  d.server_password = 'myPassword'
end


God.contact(:email) do |c|
  c.name = 'me'
  c.group = 'developers'
  c.to_email = 'me@example.com'
end     

w.start_if do |start|
  start.condition(:process_running) do |c|
  c.interval = 20.seconds
  c.running = false
  c.notify = {:contacts => ['me'], :priority => 1, :category => 'staging'}
end
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/god-rb/browse_thread/thread/16de04baefa2e4ea/c8968f6140adbd2f) on the mailing list:

1. `gem install tlsmail`
2. add `Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)` in the email 
   part of god's config
3. Use `:login` intead of `true` for your `server_auth` setting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've done as suggested and got the following error: 
undefined method `enable_tls' for Net::SMTP:Class

here are my god email configuration:
God::Contacts::Email.defaults do |d|
  Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
  d.from_email = 'system@example.com'
  d.from_name = 'Process monitoring'
  d.delivery_method = :smtp
  d.server_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
  d.server_port = 587
  d.server_auth = :login
  d.server_domain = 'example.com'
  d.server_user = 'system@example.com'
  d.server_password = 'password'
end

Comment: I'm running into this same issue, but after following this answer I receive: (INFO: failed to send email to my@email.com via smtp: end of file reached) which is an improvement but still doesn't completely fix this for me...